# How to limit the input of a text edit

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am making an edittext, and I would like to force the user to enter a number less than 200, I have seen people showing how to limit the number of characters, but does anyone know how to limit the user input without using an 800 section if statement?  ie. The user can enter any number between 1- 199 but they cannot enter the number 201.

Comment: sorry not get exactly, In XML itself for EditText Attrib, android:maxLength="200"

Comment: Doesn't that make it two hundred characters long?

Comment: can't use spinner ? :(........

Comment: I will if I cannot figure out how to do this,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first set ur edit text input type number and after that

```
 edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){}
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){
        String strEnteredVal = edittext.getText().toString();

        if(!strEnteredVal.equals("")){
        int num=Integer.parseInt(strEnteredVal);
        if(num<200){
         edittext.setText(""+num);
        }else{
         edittext.setText("");
        }
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not clear whether you mean to limit the field to less than 200 characters, or to a number value less than 200 (e.g. "199"). If the latter, set the property `android:inputType="number"`, and then add an `OnFocusChangeListener` to the EditText, implementing the `onFocusChange()` method to check the value of the EditText and change/alert/remove if not valid.

Answer (score 1):

Number Spinner/Picker for Android

Found a handy number spinner for Android based on the Google internal number spinner (not yet made public) used in the Android Time Picker Dialog.

It is released under the Apache 2.0 and can be found

http://www.quietlycoding.com/?p=5

have

mStart = DEFAULT_MIN;
mEnd = DEFAULT_MAX;

At the top of the java file I have declared the DEFAULT_MAX and DEFAULT_MIN as such:

```
private static final int DEFAULT_MAX = 200;
private static final int DEFAULT_MIN = 0;
```

[image]